# In SQL Server - how do I exclude the phrase 'Type I' from a field, but include 'Type II'

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, where-clause, sql-like

I am looking to pull data from a text field whenever it relates to Type 2 Diabetes.

Sometimes they refer to it in Roman Numerals so it can be 'Type I Diabetes' or 'Type II Diabetes'

How do I exclude Type I but not exclude Type II? I assume there must be a way using wildcards etc

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `col like '%Type II%' or col like '%Type 2%'`

Answer (score 2):

Whether this works depends on your data, but you can include the trailing space in the match:

```
col not like '%Type I %'
```

Comment: that works thank you! Don't know how I didn't think of that

Answer (score 1):

You can use `like` and `not like`:

```
where mycol like '%Type I%' and mycol not like 'Type II%'
```